# Ansible trim string

Tags: ansible

I'm trying write role to install MySql 8, and get problem with this:

```yaml
- name: Extract root password from logs into {{ mysql_root_old_password }} variable
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: "{{ mysql_logfile_path }}"
  register: mysql_root_old_password
  #when: "'mysql' in ansible_facts.packages" 

- name: Extract root password from logs into {{ mysql_root_old_password }} variable
  set_fact:
    mysql_root_old_password: "{{ mysql_root_old_password.content | b64decode | regex_findall('generated for root@localhost: (.*)$', 'multiline=true') }}"
  #when: "'mysqld' in ansible_facts.packages" 

- name: Get Server template
  ansible.builtin.template:                                                                     
    src: "{{ item.name }}.j2" 
    dest: "{{ item.path }}"
  loop:
    - { name: "my.cnf", path: "/root/.my.cnf" }
  notify: 
    - Restart mysqld
```

on the `.my.cnf` I get password with quotes and brackets:

```ini
[client]
user=root
password=['th6k(gZeJSt4']
```

How to trim that?

What I try:

```yaml
- name: trim password
  set_fact:
    mysql_root_old_password2: "{{ mysql_root_old_password | regex_findall('[a-zA-Z0-9,()!@#$%^&*]{12}')}}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not the answer you’re looking for, but this might help you: https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_percona_xtradb_cluster/blob/main/tasks/root.yml#L21

Comment: _and get problem with this_ > this is not an accurate description of an issue, what is not working with your current attempt? Does it errors out, if so, what is the error message; does it not assign the `mysql_root_old_password2` as you expect, if so, provide what is the assigned value and what is your expected value, ...?

Comment: Regarding "_I get password with quotes and brackets ... ['<pass>'] ... How to trim that?_" please take note that from perspective of the SQL service and `.cnf` file `['` and `']` are part of the password! If that is correct they will be necessary for proper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of [*regex_findall*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) is a list because there might be more matches. Take the last item

```yaml
- set_fact:
    mysql_root_old_password: "{{ mysql_root_old_password.content|
      b64decode|
      regex_findall('generated for root@localhost: (.*)$', 'multiline=true')|
      last }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description

> *on the `.my.cnf` I get password with quotes and brackets ... How to trim that*

I understand that you like to read a INI file like `my.cnf.ini`

```ini
[client]
user=root
password=['A1234567890B']
```

where the value of the key `password` looks like a list with one element in YAML and the structure doesn't change, but you are interested in the value without leading and trailing square brackets and single quotes only.

To do so there are several possibilities.

---

Via Ansible [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Extract root password from INI file
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('ini', 'password section=client file=my.cnf.ini') }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result with type
    debug:
      msg:
        -  "{{ result.msg }}"
        -  "result.msg is of type {{ result.msg | type_debug }}"
        - "Show password only {{ result.msg[0] }}" # the first list element
```

Such approach will work on the Control Node.

> *Like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine.*

**Further Q&A**

- [How to read a line from a file into an Ansible variable](https://serverfault.com/a/952837/448950)
- [What is the difference between `.ini` and `.conf`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54957/)

**Further Documentation**

- [`ini` lookup – read data from an INI file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html)

---

Via Ansible shell module, `sed` and `cut`.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Extract root password from INI file
    shell:
      cmd: echo $(sed -n 's/^password=//p' my.cnf.ini | cut -d "'" -f 2)
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

---

Please take note regarding "*I get password with quotes and brackets ... ['<pass>'] ... How to trim that?*" that from perspective of the SQL service, `.cnf` file, `['` and `']` are actually part of the password!

```yaml
- name: Server template
  template:                                                                     
    src: "my.cnf.ini" 
    dest: "/root/.my.cnf"
```

If that is correct they will be necessary for proper function of the service.

Comment: where you got *.ini?))

Comment: Regarding your comment "_where you got `*.ini`?_", it is to show what type of data structure is used within the file `my.cnf` only and explained within the answer under the link [What is the difference between `.ini` and `.conf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54957/), "_Unlike DOS-based OSes, in Unix and Linux file extensions are mostly meaningless outside of human-readable reasons._"